# How to enable ido-ubiquitous globally

Tags: ido

I want to have [`ido-ubiquitous`](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/ido-ubiquitous) available in every buffer at all times, but I can't find what I have to add to my `.emacs` to do it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a comment at the top of [`ido-ubiquitous.el`](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/blob/bleeding-edge/ido-ubiquitous.el) (the relevant part is in **bold**):

> To use this package, call `ido-ubiquitous-mode` to enable the mode,
>   or **use `M-x customize-variable ido-ubiquitous-mode` it to enable it
>   permanently**. Note that `ido-ubiquotous-mode` has no effect unless
>   `ido-mode` is also enabled.